# Testing - how to have all loggers print output

Tags: python, logging, pytest

I'm trying to write some unit tests for a bunch of REST handlers (which are part of a custom REST framework). For the REST server, all exceptions are typically logged and code execution usually continues if possible.

As I am setting up tests, I am running into the issue of not knowing why tests are not passing. Each module with handlers contains the lines

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

On failing the test the only output, aside from the failed assert, is along the lines of

```
No handlers could be found for logger "project.handlers.module"
```

Is there a simple fix I can add to my test files to have the loggers simply output the errors (or all messages). I'm not sure how I can set the handler for each logger involved in the tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `logging.basicConfig` before running your unit tests, it will take care of setting up a default handler for you.

Comment: works for me... I added this to the `__init__.py` file of my tests folder